# What does it mean to use backpointers in a Height-Balanced tree?

Tags: c, avl-tree

I have to write a height-balanced tree code with backpointers, based on the height-balanced tree
code below. I have to modify the code below in such a way that there are no stacks
used anymore for following the path upward during rebalancing; instead each non-root
node should have an additional field up that points to the upper neighbor of the node.
These fields need to be set correctly especially in the rotations, and whenever performing
an insertion or deletion at the leaf level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

typedef int object_t;
typedef int key_t;
typedef struct tr_n_t { key_t        key;
                    struct tr_n_t  *left;
                    struct tr_n_t *right;
                    int           height; 
                      } tree_node_t;



tree_node_t *currentblock = NULL;
int    size_left;
tree_node_t *free_list = NULL;

tree_node_t *get_node()
{ tree_node_t *tmp;
  if( free_list != NULL )
  {  tmp = free_list;
     free_list = free_list -> left;
  }
  else
  {  if( currentblock == NULL || size_left == 0)
     {  currentblock = 
                (tree_node_t *) malloc( BLOCKSIZE * sizeof(tree_node_t) );
        size_left = BLOCKSIZE;
     }
     tmp = currentblock++;
     size_left -= 1;
  }
  return( tmp );
}


void return_node(tree_node_t *node)
{  node->left = free_list;
   free_list = node;
}


tree_node_t *create_tree(void)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node;
   tmp_node = get_node();
   tmp_node->left = NULL;
   return( tmp_node );
}

void left_rotation(tree_node_t *n)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node;
   key_t        tmp_key;
   tmp_node = n->left; 
   tmp_key  = n->key;
   n->left  = n->right;        
   n->key   = n->right->key;
   n->right = n->left->right;  
   n->left->right = n->left->left;
   n->left->left  = tmp_node;
   n->left->key   = tmp_key;
}

void right_rotation(tree_node_t *n)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node;
   key_t        tmp_key;
   tmp_node = n->right; 
   tmp_key  = n->key;
   n->right = n->left;        
   n->key   = n->left->key;
   n->left  = n->right->left;  
   n->right->left = n->right->right;
   n->right->right  = tmp_node;
   n->right->key   = tmp_key;
}

object_t *find(tree_node_t *tree, key_t query_key)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node;
   if( tree->left == NULL )
     return(NULL);
   else
   {  tmp_node = tree;
      while( tmp_node->right != NULL )
      {   if( query_key < tmp_node->key )
               tmp_node = tmp_node->left;
          else
               tmp_node = tmp_node->right;
      }
      if( tmp_node->key == query_key )
         return( (object_t *) tmp_node->left );
      else
         return( NULL );
   }
}


int insert(tree_node_t *tree, key_t new_key, object_t *new_object)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node;
   int finished;
   if( tree->left == NULL )
   {  tree->left = (tree_node_t *) new_object;
      tree->key  = new_key;
      tree->height = 0;
      tree->right  = NULL; 
   }
   else
     {  tree_node_t * path_stack[100]; int  path_st_p = 0;
      tmp_node = tree; 
      while( tmp_node->right != NULL )
      {   path_stack[path_st_p++] = tmp_node;
          if( new_key < tmp_node->key )
               tmp_node = tmp_node->left;
          else
               tmp_node = tmp_node->right;
      }
      /* found the candidate leaf. Test whether key distinct */
      if( tmp_node->key == new_key )
         return( -1 );
      /* key is distinct, now perform the insert */ 
      {  tree_node_t *old_leaf, *new_leaf;
         old_leaf = get_node();
         old_leaf->left = tmp_node->left; 
         old_leaf->key = tmp_node->key;
         old_leaf->right  = NULL;
         old_leaf->height = 0;
         new_leaf = get_node();
         new_leaf->left = (tree_node_t *) new_object; 
         new_leaf->key = new_key;
         new_leaf->right  = NULL;
         new_leaf->height = 0; 
         if( tmp_node->key < new_key )
         {   tmp_node->left  = old_leaf;
             tmp_node->right = new_leaf;
             tmp_node->key = new_key;
         } 
         else
         {   tmp_node->left  = new_leaf;
             tmp_node->right = old_leaf;
         } 
         tmp_node->height = 1;
      }
      /* rebalance */
      finished = 0;
      while( path_st_p > 0 && !finished )
      {  int tmp_height, old_height;
         tmp_node = path_stack[--path_st_p];
         old_height= tmp_node->height;
         if( tmp_node->left->height - 
                                 tmp_node->right->height == 2 )
         {  if( tmp_node->left->left->height - 
                                 tmp_node->right->height == 1 )
            {  right_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_node->right->height = 
                            tmp_node->right->left->height + 1;
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->right->height + 1;
            }
            else
            {  left_rotation( tmp_node->left );
               right_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_height = tmp_node->left->left->height; 
               tmp_node->left->height  = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->right->height = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->height = tmp_height + 2; 
            }
         }
         else if ( tmp_node->left->height - 
                                tmp_node->right->height == -2 )
         {  if( tmp_node->right->right->height - 
                                  tmp_node->left->height == 1 )
            {  left_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_node->left->height = 
                           tmp_node->left->right->height + 1;
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->left->height + 1;
            }
            else
            {  right_rotation( tmp_node->right );
               left_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_height = tmp_node->right->right->height; 
               tmp_node->left->height  = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->right->height = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->height = tmp_height + 2; 
            }
         }
         else /* update height even if there was no rotation */ 
         {  if( tmp_node->left->height > tmp_node->right->height )
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->left->height + 1;
            else
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->right->height + 1;
         }
         if( tmp_node->height == old_height )
            finished = 1;
      }

   }
   return( 0 );
}



object_t *delete(tree_node_t *tree, key_t delete_key)
{  tree_node_t *tmp_node, *upper_node, *other_node;
   object_t *deleted_object; int finished;
   if( tree->left == NULL )
      return( NULL );
   else if( tree->right == NULL )
   {  if(  tree->key == delete_key )
      {  deleted_object = (object_t *) tree->left;
         tree->left = NULL;
         return( deleted_object );
      }
      else
         return( NULL );
   }
   else
   {  tree_node_t * path_stack[100]; int path_st_p = 0;
      tmp_node = tree;
      while( tmp_node->right != NULL )
      {   path_stack[path_st_p++] = tmp_node;  
          upper_node = tmp_node;
          if( delete_key < tmp_node->key )
          {  tmp_node   = upper_node->left; 
             other_node = upper_node->right;
          } 
          else
          {  tmp_node   = upper_node->right; 
             other_node = upper_node->left;
          } 
      }
      if( tmp_node->key != delete_key )
         deleted_object = NULL;
      else
      {  upper_node->key   = other_node->key;
         upper_node->left  = other_node->left;
         upper_node->right = other_node->right;
         upper_node->height = other_node->height;
         deleted_object = (object_t *) tmp_node->left;
         return_node( tmp_node );
         return_node( other_node );

      }
      /*start rebalance*/  
      finished = 0; path_st_p -= 1;
      while( path_st_p > 0 && !finished )
      {  int tmp_height, old_height;
         tmp_node = path_stack[--path_st_p];
         old_height= tmp_node->height;
         if( tmp_node->left->height - 
                                 tmp_node->right->height == 2 )
         {  if( tmp_node->left->left->height - 
                                 tmp_node->right->height == 1 )
        {  right_rotation( tmp_node ); 
               tmp_node->right->height = 
                            tmp_node->right->left->height + 1;
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->right->height + 1;
            }
            else
        {  left_rotation( tmp_node->left ); 
               right_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_height = tmp_node->left->left->height; 
               tmp_node->left->height  = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->right->height = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->height = tmp_height + 2; 
            }
         }
         else if ( tmp_node->left->height - 
                                tmp_node->right->height == -2 )
         {  if( tmp_node->right->right->height - 
                                  tmp_node->left->height == 1 )
        {  left_rotation( tmp_node ); 
               tmp_node->left->height = 
                           tmp_node->left->right->height + 1;
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->left->height + 1;
            }
            else
            {  right_rotation( tmp_node->right );
               left_rotation( tmp_node );
               tmp_height = tmp_node->right->right->height; 
               tmp_node->left->height  = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->right->height = tmp_height + 1; 
               tmp_node->height = tmp_height + 2; 
            }
         }
         else /* update height even if there was no rotation */ 
         {  if( tmp_node->left->height > tmp_node->right->height )
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->left->height + 1;
            else
               tmp_node->height = tmp_node->right->height + 1;
         }
         if( tmp_node->height == old_height )
        finished = 1;
      }
      /*end rebalance*/
      return( deleted_object );
   }
}


void check_tree( tree_node_t *tr, int depth, int lower, int upper )
{  if( tr->left == NULL )
   {  printf("Tree Empty\n"); return; }
   if( tr->key < lower || tr->key >= upper )
         printf("Wrong Key Order \n");
   if( tr->right == NULL )
   {  if( *( (int *) tr->left) == 10*tr->key + 2 )
         printf("%d(%d)  ", tr->key, depth );
      else
         printf("Wrong Object \n");
   }
   else
   {  check_tree(tr->left, depth+1, lower, tr->key ); 
      check_tree(tr->right, depth+1, tr->key, upper ); 
   }
}

int main()
{  tree_node_t *searchtree;
   char nextop;
   searchtree = create_tree();
   printf("Made Tree: Height-Balanced Tree\n");
   while( (nextop = getchar())!= 'q' )
   { if( nextop == 'i' )
     { int inskey,  *insobj, success;
       insobj = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
       scanf(" %d", &inskey);
       *insobj = 10*inskey+2;
       success = insert( searchtree, inskey, insobj );
       if ( success == 0 )
         printf("  insert successful, key = %d, object value = %d, \
                  height is %d\n",
              inskey, *insobj, searchtree->height );
       else
           printf("  insert failed, success = %d\n", success);
     }  
     if( nextop == 'f' )
     { int findkey, *findobj;
       scanf(" %d", &findkey);
       findobj = find( searchtree, findkey);
       if( findobj == NULL )
         printf("  find failed, for key %d\n", findkey);
       else
         printf("  find successful, found object %d\n", *findobj);
     }
     if( nextop == 'd' )
     { int delkey, *delobj;
       scanf(" %d", &delkey);
       delobj = delete( searchtree, delkey);
       if( delobj == NULL )
         printf("  delete failed for key %d\n", delkey);
       else
         printf("  delete successful, deleted object %d, height is now %d\n", 
             *delobj, searchtree->height);
     }
     if( nextop == '?' )
     {  printf("  Checking tree\n"); 
        check_tree(searchtree,0,-1000,1000);
        printf("\n");
        if( searchtree->left != NULL )
      printf("key in root is %d, height of tree is %d\n", 
         searchtree->key, searchtree->height );
        printf("  Finished Checking tree\n"); 
     }
   }
   return(0);
}
```

What does "using backpointers" and "there are no stacks used anymore" mean? Do I have to modify the `/* start rebalancing */` part as well as the functions `rotation` and `insert`? I somewhat understand how a height-balanced tree works but I don't really get what I have to do for this assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this question already has an answer, I've made your questions slightly more obvious by moving them to the end and adding minimal code formatting where it was needed. Usually it's not recommended to copy and paste assignments on Stack Overflow unless there are specific questions, but there did appear to be a question or two in here that could be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your starting tree structure, each node has pointers to its left and right children (if any), but not to its parent node.  If you need to perform an operation on such a tree that requires knowledge of some or all of the path from the root of the tree to some node of interest, then you need to *construct* that path by traversing the tree and recording the path as you go -- for instance, in a stack data structure.  You cannot work backward from the end node.

You can see just such behaviour in the code you posted.  For example, in function `insert()` you have ...

```
         tree_node_t * path_stack[100]; int  path_st_p = 0;
```

... and later ...

```
             path_stack[path_st_p++] = tmp_node;
```

... and so forth.

If, on the other hand, each node also had a pointer to its parent node, you wouldn't need to track paths through the tree.  Instead, you could start at any node and go backward up the tree as far as needed, because the information necessary to do so would be carried by the nodes themselves.  The assignment is asking you to change the tree implementation to use that approach instead of the stack-based approach it uses now.

Having "back" or parent pointers is convenient in some ways, but inconvenient in others.  They yield simpler expressions for a number of things, and require less bookkeeping during tree traversal.  They may also allow you to share code more effectively among your tree functions.  On the other hand, they are an additional item to be managed whenever and wherever you modify the tree, and they introduce redundancy, in the bad sense that they yield the opportunity for inconsistency.

Your assignment starts with adding a back pointer to `struct tr_n_t`.  You must then handle initializing it correctly whenever you add a node to the tree, and updating it whenever you reparent a node as a direct result of a deletion or in the process of rebalancing.  You will furthermore remove the code in both `insert()` and `delete()` that tracks the path through the tree to the insertion point / node to delete, and modify the rebalancing code in both functions so that it uses the new back pointers to walk back up the tree instead of using stacks as it does now.